# Unfortunately App has Stopped - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

I am writing an App in which i am allowing user to enter their details, but i am getting an error, whenever user click on Submit Button, error says : **Unfortunately App has Stopped**

*android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException*

**Logcat Says:**

```
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.cart.RegistrationActivity.getHttpPost(RegistrationActivity.java:183)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.cart.RegistrationActivity.SaveData(RegistrationActivity.java:135)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.cart.RegistrationActivity$1.onClick(RegistrationActivity.java:49)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-11 14:25:07.297: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In android codes which are taking too much time to run should not be done on the main thread.So move your such codes into AsyncTask or any other methods to do it on another thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can not call **Network Operation in Main Thread in higher version of Android**. So Take one worker Thread or asynchronous task to perform Network operation Like Calling **Webservice**, Downloading Image and other.

This does not allow to make android application more responsive and smooth

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you make network connections on your main thread on honeycomb and higher versions. You should use `AsyncTask` to do all your Network operations. `AsyncTask` does your operations on the background thread. Click [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGIQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Farticles%2FAndroidBackgroundProcessing%2Farticle.html&ei=gnxmUdbCCIWQrgeQ1ICgCQ&usg=AFQjCNFKrZXBLP-ji0FvKge-lvQRBkp-qw&sig2=7qtLD0SYXfuJdgJwfD930g&bvm=bv.45107431,d.bmk&cad=rja) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FAsyncTask.html&ei=gnxmUdbCCIWQrgeQ1ICgCQ&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=KGbzkzXLXKtBD4WUUvrtfw&bvm=bv.45107431,d.bmk) to get an idea about `AsyncTask`.